# Optional Data Attributes on Input [Html]

Tags: c#, html, attributes, html-helper, custom-data-attribute

Is there a way to have an optional data attribute i.e `data_val_required` or `required` on an input/select?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PositionId, Model.Positions, new
{
    CurrentInput.Required ? data_val_required = "Please select a position" : noAttribute
})
```

My current scenario is that the dropdown lists are in a for loop which have a required property. So some of the inputs require a value while others dont. The only way I can think of doing it is wrapping the `Html.DropDownListFor` in a if statement that checks if the input is to be required and ouputs the correct html but thats code duplication.

Comment: Why don't use [Data Annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)?

Comment: The code Im current doing is a lot more complicated than this scenario and Data Annotations wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an extension of object to add these properties to the `htmlAttributes` object. The extension of accepts a list of `Item` which is a custom class that has a `Name` and `Key` property. Then I use this to add the properties that I need for certain `Inputs`.

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> AddProperties(this object obj, List<Item> properties)
{
    var dictionary = obj.ToDictionary();
    properties.ForEach(x => dictionary.Add(x.Name, x.Vale));
    return dictionary;
}
```